# How to store json content to CosmosDB with CreateDocumentAsync

Tags: c#, json, azure, azure-cosmosdb

TARGET: Create Console Application, which 1) Read json from Azure Data Lake Store 2) Store data to Cosmos DB as json. (In next step I will parse json contents in code before storing)

PROBLEM: New Document is created in CosmosDB, but it contains some kind of meta data instead of actual json file content. String json do include content I need, but it is not passed correctly to CreateDocumentAsync. I would appreciate help with fixing issue and also appreciate tips to make code easy to handle json.

ERROR: No error messages, but wrong content is stored to CosmosDB.

CODE:

```
private  async Task CreateDocumentsAsync()
    {
        string fileName = "/myjson.json";

        // Obtain AAD token for ADLS 
        var creds = new ClientCredential(applicationId, clientSecret);
        var clientCreds = ApplicationTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync(tenantId, creds).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        // Create ADLS client object
        AdlsClient client = AdlsClient.CreateClient(adlsAccountFQDN, clientCreds);

        String json = "";

        //Read file contents
        using (var readStream = new StreamReader(client.GetReadStream(fileName)))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = readStream.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Read file Line: " + line);
                json += line;
            }
        }

        //Read file to json
        JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(json));

        //Storing json to CosmosDB
        Uri collectionUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(databaseName, collectionName);

        using (DocumentClient DocumentDBclient2 = new DocumentClient(new Uri(endpointUrl), authorizationKey))
        {
            Document doc = await DocumentDBclient2.CreateDocumentAsync(collectionUri, reader);

        }
    }

}
```

JSON SAMPLE(I want to store this):

```
[
{
    color: "red",
    value: "#f00"
},
{
    color: "green",
    value: "#0f0"
},
{
    color: "blue",
    value: "#00f"
},
{
    color: "cyan",
    value: "#0ff"
},
{
    color: "magenta",
    value: "#f0f"
},
{
    color: "yellow",
    value: "#ff0"
},
{
    color: "black",
    value: "#000"
}
]
```

JSON STORED TO COSMOSDB:

```
{
"ArrayPool": null,
"LineNumber": 0,
"LinePosition": 0,
"CloseInput": true,
"SupportMultipleContent": false,
"QuoteChar": "\u0000",
"DateTimeZoneHandling": 3,
"DateParseHandling": 1,
"FloatParseHandling": 0,
"DateFormatString": null,
"MaxDepth": null,
"TokenType": 0,
"Value": null,
"ValueType": null,
"Depth": 0,
"Path": "",
"Culture": "(Default)",
"id": "0189f287-b6ae-4e45-95b8-879293d4c8f3",
"_rid": "nDxrAL1JbwYIAAAAAAAAAA==",
"_self": "dbs/nDxrAA==/colls/nDxrAL1JbwY=/docs/nDxrAL1JbwYIAAAAAAAAAA==/",
"_etag": "\"00006cc5-0000-0000-0000-5a633c900000\"",
"_attachments": "attachments/",
"_ts": 1516453008
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include 2 things: JSON data you’re sending and the actual value stored.

Comment: Thanks for interest to help me. I have added sample json.

Comment: @Keke - there is not enough information provided. For example: You talk about your JSON content not storing correctly. Great: Show what you're seeing being stored. We cannot guess what you mean by "some kind of metadata." Also, the sample JSON you shared: is that exactly what is in `reader`? Please edit to be more clear. Without more clarity, anything posted here will merely be a guess.

Comment: Thanks. I have added actually stored json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned that you store the different json to the documentDb, the root reason is that you store the `JsonTextReader` object to documentDB.

If you want to store the Jarry to the documentDB, you could store it as a property value of a Json object.

```
var jObject = new JObject {{"Data", json}};

Document doc = await DocumentDBclient2.CreateDocumentAsync(collectionUri, jObject);
```

[image]

**Note:** Based on my test it is not supported to store Jarray object directly to the documentDb. I test it with Azure portal.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. You need to put JsonProperty attribute on your properties. Something like this

```
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "LastUpdatedByName")]
    public string LastUpdatedByName { get; set; }
```